# How to launch Android apps using URL link in web browser ?

Tags: android, html

I have been trying to launch my Android app from a web browser link using the following code.

Please help me to fix/adjust the manifest file and and href code to call my application

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.rose.MoveMobile">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:name=".app.MyApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:replace="android:icon">
        <activity
            android:name=".Start"
            android:configChanges="orientation"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <data android:scheme=".app.MyApplication" android:host="com.example.rose.MoveMobile"/>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**HTML code**

```
<a href="http://MoveMobile.com.example.rose.MoveMobile">Launch Apps</a>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your URL has a scheme of `http`. Your `<intent-filter>` has a scheme of `.app.MyApplication`. These are not the same. Change your `<intent-filter>` to use `http`, or change both to something else that the browser will accept (I suspect that `.app.MyApplication` is not a valid scheme).

Also, please note that browsers are not required to launch apps from links. They may, but they may not. It is up to the browser developer.

Comment: Is it like this ? <data android:scheme="http" android:host="com.example.rose.MoveMobile"/> . So how about the HTML code ? i'm really confuse .

Comment: @Jamilah: "Is it like this ?" -- that better matches your URL in your HTML.

Answer (score 0):

```
        <data android:scheme="http"
            android:host="example.com"
            android:pathPrefix="/myPath" />
```

This would match everything starting with http://example.com/myPath

So wither you need to change your scheme to http, or you need to change the link in your  tag to use a custom scheme like myapp://somehost/somepath

Comment: Thanks . i will try your suggestion first :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<activity
        android:name=".Start"
        android:configChanges="orientation"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <data android:scheme="app" android:host="com.example.rose.MoveMobile"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Html code:
app://com.example.rose.MoveMobile

Comment: Thank you for the answer.  I'll try it first . :)